# Block apk Install (Using Root Privileges)

Tags: android

I am trying to write a program to check certain properties of .apks before allowing them to be installed (using root privileges).

The problem that I am encountering is that I am having difficulty determining when an install event is going to occur - I know that there exists an intent for when an apk has been installed, but that's too late.

I'm thinking that the easiest way of doing this may be to attempt to hook into the API that installs apks, or to receive an undocumented intent, but I am unable to find any information on either of these.

Comment: I think you will probably have to replace pieces of android that accomplish the installation with modified versions.